# Integration tests with nHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nhibernate

Ok, here's the deal.

I have a webApi project in ASP.NET Core, that references project int .NET Framework with nHibernate.

I want to design some integration tests but I can't figure out the way to hook up SQLite driver.

I've end up with something like this:

```
Configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

IDictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    // Setup database connection
    {NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionProvider, "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"},
    {NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, "NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect"},
    {NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, "MilestoneTG.NHibernate.Driver.Sqlite.Microsoft.MicrosoftSqliteDriver, MilestoneTG.NHibernate.Driver.Sqlite.Microsoft"},
    {NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, "Data Source=:memory:;New=True;"},
    {NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Isolation, "ReadCommitted"},
    {NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "call"}
};

Configuration.AddProperties(properties);

Configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(NHibernateConfiguration).Assembly);


var export = new SchemaExport(Configuration);
export.Execute(true, true, false);

SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

SchemaExport.Execute() throws an Exception telling me that SQLite dialect cannot deal with DbType.DateTimeOffset.

Natural way out of this would be using the custom convention but I cannot do that because it's asp.net core :/

All mappings are stored in hbm.xml files.
I cannot modify nHibernate configuration.
I have to stick up with asp.net core.

Additionally, only one class uses DateTimeOffset and it's rather expendable, but I can't figure out the way to import all other classes except this one.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: so your real question is how to map DateTimeOffset to Sqlite using Nhibernate and .net core?       Your actual question title has nothing to do with the question you are asking and nothing to do with integration testing

Comment: Nope. I know how to map DateTimeOffset to Sqllite using nHibernate and .net core. What I don't know is how to prepare an environment for integration testing in .net core for nHibernate without using Fluent configuration or remodeling original mappings manually.

Comment: Why is .Net core a barrier to using HBM files? I've not used NH on .Net Core yet, so I'm interested to know.

Comment: It's not. The problem I have here is that one of classes in model uses DateTimeOffset property and it's not translateable in Sqlite dialect.

Comment: You can selectively add mappings (http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-programmatic). Whilst not ideal, as your testing environment is not representative of your release one, you could create a way of loading all mappings by default but then overriding these for testing, omitting the one with the DateTimeOffset.

Comment: Since my *.hbm.xml files are oriented in another assembly, I'm guessing I would have to copy them to the output directory, right? That's kind of a dealbreaker because it would affect other applications using data model.

Answer (score 1):

I've made it to work. Not in the elegant way but still.

As I mentioned before there was one class that was problematic because of DateTimeOffset property.

One option was to get rid of this class from model.

I couldn't use AddClass() method to add all classes but this one because naming convention wasn't preserved. So I figured a workaround:

I've iterated through all classes (except the problematic one) and built "*.hbm.xml" file names for each of them and then I've used AddResource() method to add each file to configuration.

```
foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(BaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.Name != nameof(ProblematicType) && !t.IsAbstract))
{
    var mappingName = string.Join(".", type.Namespace.Replace("Model", "DataMapping"), type.Name) + ".hbm.xml";
    configuration.AddResource(mappingName, assembly);
}
```

It would look something like that (I've omitted project specific lines).

I know it's probably not the best way to do it and of course it doesn't fix the root problem but it works fine.